# Accessing DataFrame Cell By Column Name

Tags: python, dataframe

I have string variable idx which contains a string [a column name of a Dataframe].
I want to access the cell with first row and that specific column.

```
print(idx)
>>>> Contract
```

I tried,

```
print(df.iloc[0][idx])
```

but, getting,

```
KeyError: 'Contract'
```

How to access that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update it like below and see if it is working or not:

```
print(df.loc[0:idx])
```

And also try this:

```
print(df.iloc[0,idx])
```